# How can I get exact urls of product images in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I got products from product and product_description tables. I also found image column in product table. But I can't get resized images? How can I?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2):

Resized images are stored in `image/cache/` folder.

Resized images are created only when resize method is called. Like in `catalog/controller/product/product.php` you can see following code which will resize the main image.

```
$this->load->model('tool/image');

        if ($product_info['image']) {
            $data['popup'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height'));
        } else {
            $data['popup'] = '';
        }
```

Here the resize method takes database product's table image field and height and width given in setting of admin.

This will create resized image at `image/cache/"IF ANY FOLDER"/` and the name of the image will be like "NAME_OF_THE_IMAGE"-width*height."EXTENSION_OF_IMAGE"

For eg:
If you product table's image column holds `catalog/demo/imac.jpg` then you resize it with width=100 and height=100  then it will be `cache/catalog/demo/imac-100*100.jpg`

Take into consideration that resized images are created only when you load the controller, once it is created it will be there.

So taking your problem into consideration, you have to recreate your image urls as described above and create resized images(only if you need images also).